# Ionic installation in ubuntu 14.04 failed

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I have this issue when trying to install Ionic.

```
mypc@mypc-HP-ProBook-470-G2:~$ sudo npm install -g ionic
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-1.7.14.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-1.7.14.tgz
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/connect/node_modules/finalhandler requires debug@'1.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data requires combined-stream@'~0.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
ionic@1.7.14 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
```

Can someone help me to solve it, please ?

Thanks.

Comment: try to install without sudo

Comment: when I try to install without sudo, it's give an errors : npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/ionic'

Comment: remove ionic with sudo, then install again without sudo

Comment: how can I dot it ? sudo apt-get remove ionic*     ???

Comment: Sudo npm uninstall ionic

Comment: I did it but when I try to install without sudo, I have an error (permission right)

Comment: Same dep problem on windows with npm install -g ionic

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it;s the `npm` and `nodejs` version which is wrong. 
(*At least it was in my case*)

I believe this has to do with the later added feature of [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

---

Update to a later version of node, I am not sure, if you are on ubuntu specifically or not, but for this purpose I was using ubuntu 14.x.

Remove all nodejs installs you might currently have :

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs`

then you want to install node through the [NVM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm)

You can search for a version you want via :

`nvm ls-remote`

For the ionic install I updated to : v0.12.10

`nvm install 0.12.10`

After this installs (It's also going to install/update npm for you)

You should see your latest version :

`node -v`

Should display : `v.0.12.10` in this case.

You may then continue to install the ionic framework as instructed .

`npm install -g ionic`

**Note:** *NVM also allows you to have concurrent installs of different node versions. Very handy for some legacy apps // services.*